# I'm facing some problems on installing packages on kali linux armhf on linux deploy

Tags: kali-linux

: The repository 'http://security.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://security.kali.org/kali-security/dists/sana/updates/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
root@localhost:~#

how to fix those errors

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the `README` file at `http://security.kali.org/kali-security/README`:

> This was Kali Linux's security package repository: http://security.kali.org/
>
> With Kali Rolling (2016.x), this repository is no longer needed as security
>   updates come directly from new upstream releases to the Debian Testing
>   distribution.
>
> **It was kept alive as long as Kali 2.0 "sana" was available on the main mirror,
>   this is no longer the case and thus this repository is discontinued and will
>   be dropped in the near future.**
>
> **You can find a backup of the sana/updates repository on old.kali.org if you
>   still need it. The corresponding entry in /etc/apt/sources.list would be:**
>
> **deb http://old.kali.org/kali-security sana/updates main contrib non-free**
>
> --
>
> Kali Linux, the most advanced penetration testing distribution, ever.
>
> http://www.kali.org

Comment: okay I will try to remove those security lines from sources.list thanks for ans man

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://http.kali.org/kali sana Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://http.kali.org/kali/dists/sana/main/binary-armhf/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Still showing some errors

Comment: @user6495452 Please take note of the portion of the `README` file that I put in bold.  Removing the security lines may have eliminated some warnings but it does not solve the problem as addressed in the `README`.  Also, it is better to put the content of your comment above as an edit to your post.

Comment: yes sir now it's working as you said I remove those security lines now it's all working good thanks sir